# JavaFX Saving editable TableView to SQL

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have created a two column editable TableView which the user can edit and change the data thats inside each cell. Now my question is, once the user has changed some data around in each cell, how do I then save this data or print it out in a way to add to an SQL query like this example below

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (Value from table,Value from table,Value from table,...);
```

//Editable cell

```
PriceColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
PriceColumn.setOnEditCommit(
        new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<NewCustomerList, String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<NewCustomerList, String> t) {
                ((NewCustomerList) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setPrice(t.getNewValue());
            }
        }
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this by getting the required values and then passing them onto the DAO class to execute the query on the DB. Example follows-

```
PriceColumn.setOnEditCommit(
        new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<NewCustomerList, String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<NewCustomerList, String> t) {
                ((NewCustomerList) t.getTableView().getItems().get(t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setPrice(t.getNewValue());
                String newPrice = t.getNewValue();
                String uniqueIdentifier = t.getRowValue().getUniqueIdentifier(); //Unique identfier is something that uniquely identify the row. It could be the name of the object that we are pricing here.
                daoObj.updatePrice(newPrice, uniqueIdentifier); //Call DAO now
            }
        }
);
```

And somewhere in the deep dark jungles of `DAO` class,

```
private final String updateQuery = "UPDATE <TABLE_NAME> SET <PRICE_COLUMN> = ? WHERE <UNIQUE_COLUMN> = ?"; //If you require multiple columns to get a unique row, add them in the where clause as well.

public void updatePrice(String newPrice, String uniqueIdentifier) {
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(updateQuery); //con is the connection object
    ps.setString(1,uniqIdentifier); //if a string
    ps.setString(2,newPrice); //if a string
    ps.executeQuery();
}
```

If this is not what you were expecting, then can you please clarify your requirement?